# How to group by ID as well as date with this query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

This is a followup to a question I posted [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31408089/how-to-return-value-based-on-the-last-available-timestamp-if-the-exact-time-is-u?noredirect=1#comment50791095_31408089). This code does exactly what I was asking about but I realized upon finally getting it working that what I was trying to do isn't actually quite what I need.

```
DECLARE @StartDateTime datetime = '2015-07-13 14:00:00',
        @EndDateTime datetime = '2015-07-13 16:00:00';

WITH JumpsOf15 AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY object_id) * 15 AS Step
    FROM sys.objects
),
Dates as
(
SELECT currentDate = steppedDate.steppedDate
FROM JumpsOf15
CROSS APPLY(SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE,Step,@StartDateTime) AS steppedDate ) AS steppedDate
WHERE @EndDateTime>steppedDate.steppedDate 
)

SELECT  d.currentDate, t.Value, t.FK_ConfigId
FROM    Dates AS d
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 t.[Timestamp], t.Value, t.FK_ConfigId
            FROM    myTable AS t
            WHERE   t.[Timestamp] <= d.currentDate and t.FK_ConfigId in (208812, 208809, 208815)
            ORDER BY t.[Timestamp] DESC, t.Value, t.FK_ConfigId
        ) AS t
```

This gives an output like so:

```
currentDate          value           FK_ConfigId
1/1/2015 12:15       2               208809
1/1/2015 12:30       5               208815
1/1/2015 12:45       1               208815
```

But actually I need to have one record per timestamp per unique `FK_ConfigId` that I specify in a list. Right now I am only getting one record per timestamp regardless of the config ID. The output I want:

```
currentDate          value           FK_ConfigId
1/1/2015 12:15       2               208809
1/1/2015 12:15       4               208815
1/1/2015 12:30       5               208809
1/1/2015 12:30       1               208815
```

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Start by taking out the `top 1` in your final outer apply, see what that gets you.

Comment: I need the top 1 because there can be multiple rows for each configId for each timestamp that I need. In the real data it's not so neat, I can have values at 12:16:14 and 12:16:13 for example but I want to display 12:15:00 and just take the closest one.

Comment: you don't have a `GROUP BY` clause in the query

Comment: You'll need to `group by FK_ConfigId ,currentDate`, and then you'll need to work out how to decide which 'value' to take (min, max, etc).

Comment: @Andrew thank you. I just figured it out then read your comment, lol actually telling me to take  out the Top 1 made me look at the data again and realize I needed group by. Now I feel silly. >.<

Answer (score 0):

Try this and tell me what you think:

```
DECLARE @StartDateTime datetime = '2015-07-13 14:00:00',
        @EndDateTime datetime = '2015-07-13 16:00:00';

WITH JumpsOf15 AS (
   SELECT Step = Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) * 15
   FROM sys.objects
),
Dates AS (
   SELECT currentDate = DateAdd(minute, Step, @StartDateTime)
   FROM JumpsOf15
   WHERE Step < DateDiff(minute, 0, @EndDateTime - @StartDateTime)
)
SELECT
   d.currentDate,
   t.ConfigId,
   t.Value
FROM
   Dates d
   CROSS JOIN (VALUES
      (208812), (208809), (208815)
   ) c (ConfigId)
   OUTER APPLY (
      SELECT TOP 1
          t.[Timestamp],
          t.Value,
          t.FK_ConfigId
      FROM myTable t
      WHERE
         d.currentDate >= t.[Timestamp]
         AND c.ConfigId = t.FK_ConfigId
      ORDER BY
         t.[Timestamp] DESC,
         t.Value
   ) t
;
```